# How to init a LinkedList?

Tags: c

I want to init my LinkedList, but failed.

```
typedef int ElemType;

typedef struct LNode
{
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode* next;
}LNode, *LinkedList;

void Init(LinkedList L)
{
    L = (LNode *)malloc(sizeof(LNode));
    L->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList head;
    Init(head);
    return 0;
}
```

If I Init my LinkedList like this it works.

```
LNode node = (LNode *)malloc(sizeof(int));
node->data = 5;
node->next = NULL;
LinkedList head = node;
```

but this will make my head with a value.

Comment: You need to decide which language you want an answer for `c` and `c++` are two different languages with different concepts in how to solve such task.

Comment: I've set the question's tag to `c` rather than `c++`, since the code is valid c and not in C++-flavor.

Comment: For other ideas, see [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) and then see [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) for the benefit of using a `tail` pointer providing O(1) insertions at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Init(LNode **L, ElemType data)
{
    *L = malloc(sizeof(LNode));
    (*L)->data = data;
    (*L)->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList head;
    Init(&head, 0);

    // ...

    free(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Initializing your head to not contain a value doesn't really make sense, unless you actually want `head = NULL` which I assume is not the case.

Comment: Finally got it I think, this is confusing haha.

Comment: I don't want init my list with value.Because I want use push_back() or push_front() function to add value. if I init head = NULL. All funtion that I write can't run.

Comment: `void PushBack(LinkedList L, ElemType data)
{
    LNode* node = CreateNode(data);
    if(L == NULL)
    {
        L = node;
        return;
    }
    LNode* tmp = L;
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = node;
}` This is my push_back function.

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen to define a linked list as a pointer to an element - the head element.

It's customary to initialize containers (like lists, queues, stacks etc.) to be empty. An empty list has no head element, so the pointer to the head element would be `NULL`. In other words, you would either write

```
LinkedList create_list()
{
   return NULL;
}

// ...

LinkedList mylist = create_list();
```

or

```
void initialize_list(LinkedList* list)
{
   *list = NULL;
}

// ...

LinkedList my_list;
initialize_list(&my_list);
```

The use of `malloc()` will be in functions which append or prepend a new node to the list.

Comment: I got it.I have another question.when I make my push_back() fuction like this:`push_back(LinkedList L, ElemType data)` this function run nothing in console. `push_back(LinkedList *L, ElemType data)` I can get what I want.It's confusing.

Comment: But this is an issue in C with every data type - because functions are "pass by value", not "pass by reference". Thus if you want to swap two int's, you have to write `void swap(int* a, int*b)` rather than `void swap(int a, int b)` which would do nothing.